# Почему перезаписывается (обнуляется значение) словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача и код который я уже написал:

```
3. Написать функцию thesaurus(),
принимающую в качестве аргументов имена сотрудников и возвращающую словарь, 
в котором ключи — первые буквы имен, а значения — списки, содержащие имена,
начинающиеся с соответствующей буквы.

Например:
# >>> >>> thesaurus("Иван", "Мария", "Петр", "Илья")
{
    "И": ["Иван", "Илья"],
    "М": ["Мария"], "П": ["Петр"]
}
Подумайте: полезен ли будет вам оператор распаковки?
Сможете ли вы вернуть отсортированный по ключам словарь?
```

```py
def thesaurus(*names):
    list_name = [*names]
    dictionary = {}
    list_name_1 = []
    for name in list_name:
        name.capitalize()
        char = name[0]
        dict_1 = {char : name}
        dictionary.update(dict_1)

    return dictionary

print(thesaurus("Майа", "Дарси", 'Макс'))
```

У меня обнуляется значение "Майа", не знаю как сделать, чтобы оставить ее внутри.

Пожалуйста, не пишите ответы с лямбдой и прочим, я новичек и не пойму, а мне хочется понять как решить, а не списать с вопросами о том, что это. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Ну так что тут удивительного? update заменяет старое значение на новое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

более простой вариант и без использования модулей:

```
def thesaurus(*names):
    res = {}
    for name in names:
        key = name[0].capitalize()
        if key not in res:
            res[key] = []
        res[key].append(name)
    return res
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, и просто, и круто!

Answer (score 4):

попробуйте так:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def thesaurus(*names):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for x in names:
        res[x[0]].append(x)
    return dict(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
names = ["Майа", "Дарси", 'Макс', "Макс"]

names_dict_set = dict()
names_dict_list = dict()

for name in names:
  first_letter = name[0].upper()
  # Первый вариант с множеством. Исключаем дублирование имени.
  names_dict_set[first_letter] = names_dict_set.setdefault(first_letter, set()) | {name.capitalize()}
  # Второй вариант со списком. Возможны дублирующие записи в списке
  names_dict_list[first_letter] = names_dict_list.setdefault(first_letter, []) + [name.capitalize()]

print(names_dict_set, names_dict_list, sep='\n')
# {'М': {'Майа', 'Макс'}, 'Д': {'Дарси'}}
# {'М': ['Майа', 'Макс', 'Макс'], 'Д': ['Дарси']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def thesaurus(*names):
    # set убирает дублирующие имена а title() приводит все к одному виду (майя, МАЙЯ, Майя запишутся как 1 имя Майя)
    set_names = {name.title() for name in names}
    first_letter = [name[0].upper() for name in set_names]
    # как описано в других примерах - результат (словарь) можно было реализовать с помощью from collections import defaultdict,
    # но так как мы знаем уже все ключи я бы прдпочел этот способ
    result_dict = {k: list() for k in first_letter}

    for name in set_names:
        result_dict[name[0]].append(name)

    return result_dict

print(thesaurus("Майа", "Дарси", 'Макс', 'Макс'))
```